# django delete view override delete method

Tags: django

im using the delete view and i want to customize the action of the deletion.

there are some checks i need to do before deleting the object and in case the

checks doesn't pass i want to redirect to the same view and show a matching

massage (just like i can do in the form_valid method with the form.add_error

and return self.form_invalid(form)).

so i have the following delete method:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if XXXX:
        ### add_error and return a massage ###
    else:
        return super(delete, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

what i need/can do in the "if" to prevent the deletion and explain the user

what the problem is?

thx

Answer (score 1):

To prevent deletion you just have not to call super().delete in the if clause.

For explaining why deletion was not performed you can use django messages (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/)

So I think you can use something like this in your if clause

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'Object was not deleted')
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

And you'll be able to access message text using code from django messages documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.get_messages

Comment: i imported: from django.contrib import messages and it dowsn't recognize me add_message

Comment: it say that the view doesn't have an object attribute. "object has no attribute 'object'"

Comment: @brad can you please send me a stack trace for this, because this error  doesn't seem to relate to django messages at all?